# How to manage Printers in Java

Tags: java, windows, printing

At my school we have trouble connecting to the Printers properly. It's not that they are not on the network, we just don't really know how to interface with them through our laptops.

My idea was to maybe make some kind of application (using Java) which could be used to print out Documents and the likes from the schools printers.

I've been looking at the tutorial that Oracle have made on printers (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) but there are two things I'd like to have clarified first:

1. The printers on the school use a system (either FollowMe or
   FollowYou) to keep track of who prints what on the printers, and so
   that you can tell a printer to print anywhere on the school, as long
   as you have your card to activate it. Does anyone know if this can
   be interfaced with through Java?
2. Is it possible to make an implementation in which I can right-click on a document in Windows (since that is what I use) and add a new option called "Print using JPrinter" to the list of options?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would recommend to first give the existing drivers another try before writing something on your own. Consider writing a qeustion on Superuser.com and include more details about the used printer model and OS system and so on. If you stick on the development patch Java is IMHO the wrong starting point, especially considering the third party software that has to be integrated. Dot.Net (on Windows) or C++ are the better alternatives for that task as they allow to develop closer to the platform.

Comment: @Robert I don't know enough about C++ to write programs that utilize Hardware unfortunately.

Comment: What you are suggesting is theoretically possible but _quite_ a lot of work. I was involved in a similar project at a University and believe me when I tell you it was no fun.
Especially if we're talking the big copy-scan-multi-thingy-printer machines usually found at schools and offices (you might not easily get an open API to use). Having to deal with the billing/authentication framework will also impose a further hurdle. Stay clear unless this is a project worth investing serious time.

Comment: @fgysin would be nice learning at least :)